# TDD/Unit test - OK to break existing tests

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

In the `re-factor` stage of `TDD` is it OK to break multiple existing tests as once. For example to change the constructor of a class and have to amend tests that consume that class.

The test assertion tests the `behaviour` of the code, however the implementation of the test `arrange/act` are actually testing the code itself.

> I guess to avoid multiple tests breaking the unit tests should be as dry as possible meaning that a single update should be needed if the constructor changes (where possible).

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, you should try to keep the setup code for tests in a common place so all tests can ask for an instance of some type to test from an "authoritative source". So the first step would be to refactor the tests to get the instance from a shared helper method instead of calling `new` by themselves.

Then, you can refactor the constructor to take more arguments. Now, you have a single place to fix.

I often call this helper `TestDataFactory`. It knows a bit about the object model so you can ask it for an instance of `Foo` and it will return an instance with a lot of useful test data in most fields.

Comment: Although I mostly agree with @Aaron, I wouldn't bother much about breaking multiple tests at once. The most important is that you get your code tested thoroughly. Indeed it is recommended and so do I to have a single place to change the code break, but sometimes it adds unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time, with constructors or anything else that is called in multiple places. I don't see it as a big deal, I usually just correct any tests that accidentally failed and then get on with the test I was in.

Some people have thought about techniques to avoid this though, especially for long-running refactorings where you don't want to spend hours in a not-compiling state. See the concept of ["Limited Red"](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/The-Limited-Red-Society) coined by Joshua Kerievsky for instance.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arron has already stated the first step is to re-factor early and move the code to instantiate the object with the method that you are about to test to a factory method.

e.g.

```
var sut = CreateSUT();
var result = sut.MethodUderTest();
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

For more complicated objects you may want to consider using a pattern like the test data builder pattern.  This [blog](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/) describes the pattern nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I aggre with most what have been mentioned above, but I usually do this a bit differently. I don't like to break tests outside of the scope that I would be currently working on. However, I also don't want to limit my refactoring based on some irrational "code administrative fear" (i think mental things like that creates even bigger quality issues).

So what I usually do is that I add new code with the new behavour, keeping the old for a short period of time (deprecate it), just long enough for the new functionality to stabilize. Then I tackle ALL other tests in one sweep, all at the same time, making sure you ONLY fix that.

In C# (as an example) optional parameters with default values can really help me, but otherwise I just overload or create new ctor/methods.

Doing it this way tends to keeps me much more focused on the task (test) at hand, but more important, it also keeps me merciless when refactoring. Refactoring feels more natural and less disruptive that way.

The one principal i REALLY don't apply to unit-testing is DRY. I wouldn't recommend anyone to bring that thinking over to the test-world. DRY has a tendency of creating testcases that become difficult to follow. I rather have lots of code in the tests, but easy to follow, than DRY.